# edit a Core Data Object in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I push an object that comes from the Core Data Database to a detail page with text fields.

When the user changes the text in the textfields and presses save the changes should be saved to the core data DB.

Problem: I have no clue how to modify/update/change an existing core data entity.

I probably need to get the original via a @FetchRequest but every time I try I get some problems.

> Question 1: Let's say the entity has object.id as UUID, how can I
> fetch that object in SwiftUI?
>
> Question 2: How can I overwrite the fetched object with the changed
> content of the textfields?

```
    struct ProductDetail: View {
    @State var barcode: Barcode
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    //let datahandler = Datahandler()

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Barcode: ")
                Spacer()
                TextField("Barcode", text: Binding($barcode.code, ""))
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 250, alignment: .trailing)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Amount: ")
                Spacer()
                TextField("Amount", text: Binding($barcode.amount, ""))
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 250, alignment: .trailing)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
            HStack{
                Button("Back") {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Save"){
                    //self.datahandler.updateBarcode(barcode: self.object)
                    self.editBarcode(barcode: barcode)
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }
        .padding()
        }
    .padding()
    }
    
    func editBarcode(barcode: Barcode) {
        

// Question 1: Fetch Original object using barcode.id
// Question 2: How to but barcode into context so it can overwrite the core data original?

        try? context.save()
    }
```

Attempt:

```
    func editBarcode(barcode: Barcode) {
        @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "self.id IN %@", barcode.id)) var results: FetchedResults<Barcode>
        results.first?.amount = barcode.amount
        results.first?.code = barcode.code
        try? context.save()
    }
```

Errors:

> Argument type 'UUID?' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'
>
> Cannot use instance member 'barcode' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available
>
> Property wrappers are not yet supported on local properties